# How to set the id property of mat-option in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I access and set the value of the id attribute of mat-option from a TypeScript file when using the HTML code
Below my code:

`<mat-option [id]=”item.id” [value]=”item.name” >` ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do so, is to declare a property in your ts file and bind this property to the id attribute

In html : `<mat-option [id]=”propName” [value]=”item.name” >`

In ts : `propName: string = 'option1';`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using mat-option tag inside a mat-select tag. if you use a ng-model or formcontrol in the mat-select tag, we can get the selected option value.
eg:

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="studentId">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let item of studentList" [value]="item.id">{{item.studentName}} 
   </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

here you can access the selected option value by accessing the studentId variable